# Show transition when jumping between slides

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, slideshow

In short - I want a transition shown on slide when I select it while presenting, through "See All slides" -> click on any slide.

Longer version - I plan using a powerpoint slideshow in d&d, second screen pointed to players in which I would visualize monsters, clues for puzzles etc. The reason why I need transition -> Adding sound effect when showing a new slide and since sound effects are tied to transitions, they are not played If i select a specific slide instead of going through them sequentially.